# Should Google news and Google sitemap index contains all posts in the site?

Tags: sitemap

I have a big database of 5M post, and I have sitemap index [like this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en)
but without **lastmod**, and because of this large number of posts it will be hard if I make and sitemap index contains 100000 sitemap and each sitemap contains 1000 posts,
so what about if I just include the posts of last month in these sitemap index?

Will it affect the Google indexing and Google news indexing?

Comment: I am not sure I understand this. Sitemaps are easy. I have created sitemaps with 1 million +/- pages - easy peasy. Blink of an eye! I would not be creative on short-cutting something important.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand either but It'd only be hard if you hand-create the sitemaps line by line. You might want to look at some sitemap generators.

Comment: i mean if the sitemap conans the whole posts it will make the server die